# at91sam7 dont work after system reboot. how to force a restart?

Tags: arm, microcontroller, watchdog

I am using **at91sam7s64** header board in my project and everything works fine i use usb port to read and write data from micro controller . but when the windows or Linux get reboot or waked up after a standby the device don't work anymore and i have to disconnect/connect the device from USB port. on windows i,m using hidapi library to comunicate with device.
is there any way to force **at91sam7s** to restart itself in this situation with watchdog or any other way?

### upade

I run my code from Flash NOT RAM. It seems that "Windows have two USB reset types inside. A soft reset is just reset signaling on the bus. It resets communication pipes, but drivers already loaded remain active. A hard reset will build up the whole driver tree on top of the device. On the device side you cant see any difference"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with watchdog codes from [makecontroller](https://code.google.com/p/makecontroller/source/browse/firmware/branches/chibios/core/makingthings/watchdog.c?r=1523)

**solution:**

```
watchdogEnable(2000); // start the countdown

  void MyTask()
  {
    while (1) {
      if (everything_is_normal()) {
        watchdogReset();
      }
      else {
        // if things are not normal, the timer is not reset and will eventually expire
      }
    }
  }
```

---

### files:

watchdog.c

```
#include "config.h"
#ifdef WATCHDOG_ENABLE

#include "watchdog.h"
#include "at91sam7.h"

#define WATCHDOG_KEY (0xA5 << 24)

/**
  \defgroup Watchdog
  The Watchdog timer resets the board in the event that it's not behaving as expected.
  This is more robust than using other kinds of timers, because in the worst case, when
  your app has malfunctioned, it can still reset since it's not relying on your app to
  actually be running.

  \section Usage
  The watchdog is disabled by default.  If you want to make use of it, add the following
  line to your config.h file: \code #define WATCHDOG_ENABLE \endcode

  If you want to use it, specify the length of the countdown to watchdogEnable() and then
  periodically call watchdogReset() to reset the countdown.  If the countdown ever gets
  all the way to zero, the board will reset.

  \b Example
  \code
  watchdogEnable(2000); // start the countdown

  void MyTask()
  {
    while (1) {
      if (everything_is_normal()) {
        watchdogReset();
      }
      else {
        // if things are not normal, the timer is not reset and will eventually expire
      }
    }
  }
  \endcode
  \ingroup Core
  @{
*/

/**
  Enable the watchdog timer.
  Specify the number of milliseconds that the watchdog should wait before 
  resetting.  Remember that watchdogEnable() or watchdogDisable() can only be called
  once until the processor is reset again.

  The maximum countdown length is 16 seconds (16000 ms).
  @param millis The number of milliseconds in which a reset will occur.
*/
void watchdogEnable(int millis)
{
  int period = (millis * 256) / 1000;
  AT91C_BASE_WDTC->WDTC_WDMR =  AT91C_WDTC_WDRSTEN |        // enable reset on timeout
                                AT91C_WDTC_WDDBGHLT |       // respect debug mode
                                AT91C_WDTC_WDIDLEHLT |      // respect idle mode
                                ((period << 16 ) & AT91C_WDTC_WDD) | // delta is as wide as the period, so we can restart anytime
                                (period & AT91C_WDTC_WDV);  // set the period
}

/**
  Reset the watchdog timer countdown.
  Call watchdogEnable() first, and then call this occasionally to reset
  the watchdog countdown so that it doesn't expire.
*/
void watchdogReset()
{
  AT91C_BASE_WDTC->WDTC_WDCR = WATCHDOG_KEY | AT91C_WDTC_WDRSTT;
}

/**
  Disable the watchdog timer.
  Turn the watchdog off completely if you don't need it.

  If \b WATCHDOG_ENABLE is not defined in your config.h, this is done automatically.
*/
void watchdogDisable()
{
  AT91C_BASE_WDTC->WDTC_WDMR = AT91C_WDTC_WDDIS;
}

/** @}
*/

#endif // WATCHDOG_ENABLE
```

watchdog.h

```
#ifndef WATCHDOG_H
#define WATCHDOG_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void watchdogEnable(int millis);
void watchdogReset(void);
void watchdogDisable(void);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif // WATCHDOG_H
```

Answer (score 0):

Will it work without USB connected at the first place (if you can power the board somehow)? Try to exclude the theoretical assumption that a firmware on your board has an active communication with host operating system at your PC during the work which could lead to embedded system hang/crash when you disconnect the USB cable.

Just be clear (and better include it here in question) that you run the code from flash and not from RAM by, say, emulator from IDE.

Also you can try debugging with JTAG (if you have one) and breakpoint to illuminate the piece of code that stops an execution. The same you can try to find out with printing to some ports (like serials).

Comment: exactly there should be a problem with active communication. but how can i trigger this and rise up an interrupt internally

Comment: @osyan again, are you sure that you flash the device instead of running from RAM/emulator session?